# About adding document incrementally to Firestore React Native

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, iteration

I am currently trying to add documents to firestore incrementally. So, after a document 0, document 1 is added. After document 1, document 2 is added. However, I am having trouble making this work. I've tried a while loop but I think I get stuck in an infinite loop.

[image]

To be specific, I am trying to add a document m0, m1, m2 etc. This is my attempt at using a while loop:

```
var idofmeal = 0;
var docexists = null;
const mealref = db.collection('entirelog').doc(this.state.docid).collection('meals').doc("m" + idofmeal.toString());
                    mealref.get().then(docSnapshot => {
                        if(docSnapshot.exists) {
                            docexists = true;
                            idofmeal = idofmeal + 1;
                        } else {
                            docexists = false;
                            db.collection('entirelog')
                            .doc(this.state.docid)
                            .collection('meals')
                            .doc('m' + (idofmeal).toString())
                            .set({
                            id: this.state.idofmeal,
                            protein: this.state.protein,
                            carbohydrate: this.state.carbohyrdate,
                            foodname: this.state.foodname,
                            durl: downloadurl,
                            photoid: randomid,
                        });
                        }
                    });


                while(docexists) {
                    const mealref = db.collection('entirelog').doc(this.state.docid).collection('meals').doc("m" + idofmeal.toString());
                    mealref.get().then(docSnapshot => {
                        if (docSnapshot.exists) {
                            docexists = true;
                            idofmeal = idofmeal + 1;
                        } else {
                            docexists = false;
                            db.collection('entirelog')
                            .doc(this.state.docid)
                            .collection('meals')
                            .doc('m' + (idofmeal).toString())
                            .set({
                            id: this.state.idofmeal,
                            protein: this.state.protein,
                            carbohydrate: this.state.carbohyrdate,
                            foodname: this.state.foodname,
                            durl: downloadurl,
                            photoid: randomid,
                            });
                        }
                    });
                }
```

The logic seems really inefficient and I was wondering if there was a cleaner way to do this.

-----------------------------------------NEW EDIT
I've also tried:

```
const mealref = db.collection('entirelog').doc(this.state.docid).collection('meals').doc("m" + this.state.idofmeal.toString());
mealref.get().then(docSnapshot => {
    if(!(docSnapshot.exists)) {
        db.collection('entirelog')
        .doc(this.state.docid)
        .collection('meals')
        .doc('m' + (this.state.idofmeal).toString())
        .set({
        id: this.state.idofmeal,
        protein: this.state.protein,
        carbohydrate: this.state.carbohyrdate,
        foodname: this.state.foodname,
        durl: downloadurl,
        photoid: randomid,
    });
    } else {
        var collection = db.collection('entirelog').doc(this.state.docid).collection('meals');
        var query = collection.orderBy(firebase.firestore.FieldPath.documentId(), "desc").limit(1);
        query.get().then(function(querySnapshot) {
        querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
            console.log(doc.id);
        });
        });
    }
});
```

But, I receive this error "[Unhandled promise rejection: FirebaseError: The query requires an index. You can create it here:"
How do I add this index?

Comment: If you catch and print the entire error message (or find it in the debugger), it contains a link to the Firebase console with the exact parameters already filled in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to determine the ID of the last document in a collection when the documents are ordered by their ID. If that's the case, you can do it with:

```
var collection = db.collection('entirelog').doc(this.state.docid).collection('meals');
var query = collection.orderBy(firebase.firestore.FieldPath.documentId(), "desc").limit(1);
query.get().then(function(querySnapshot) {
  querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
    console.log(doc.id);
  });
});
```

---

If it is possible for multiple users/app instances to be writing to this collection at the same time, you'll need to ensure that they don't overwrite each other's new meals by using a transaction and/or security rules.

Comment: is "desc" a universal reference? Or, do I have to change it to something from my code?

Comment: I've tried your suggestion and I made an edit to my original post. Could you please take a look at it?

Comment: `"desc"` tells the database to return the data in descending order. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data

Comment: If you catch and print the entire error message (or find it in the debugger), it contains a link to the Firebase console with the exact parameters already filled in.

Comment: rather than using FieldPat.documentId(). I just added a document field "id" and used var query = collection.orderBy('id', "desc").limit(1); This worked for me